# how to add dialog resource in exsisting C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have a C++ project including dialog resources, now i want to add a new dialog (e.g testdialog) and i get error on this line enum {IDD = IDD_TESTDIALOG} in testdialog.h file. I have checked include directories and atlmfc is there, i am able to create a new Dialog based MFC application, cant figure out why this is happening, need help
Regards

Answer (score 1):

IDD_TESTDIALOG is defined in resource.h, so resource.h has to be #included before your testdialog.h.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the compiler can't find IDD_TESTDIALOG. Make sure you have #included resource.h.

Comment: does not it mean the same as Scott said?